# TexMaker appearance on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 recently and the appearance of my TexMaker has changed in the way which I really don't like.

Is it possible to get the good old dark blue appearance of TexMaker?

Which means that I want my TexMaker to looks like this:
[image]

However, currently it looks like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably need to find a deb containing texmaker 4.5, not sure if Ubuntu explicitly provides downgrading to 4.5.

Comment: Is not possible to change appearance in Options menu?

Comment: You can build from source, Texmaker provides all previous versions on the site. However, it's probably easier to just get used to the new look :)